# Using DocumentationBuild and Transmogrify to generate web docs

Tags: documentation, undocumented, paclets

I build my docs in Mathematica, rather than using Workbench and the DocumentationTools. But now I want to be able to build HTML versions of my docs.

I knew [Workbench (partially) supported this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/workbench-eclipse-version-html-documentation-build-html-issues) and so got the Workbench plugin for Eclipse, copied the `` DocumentationBuild` `` and `` Transmogrify` `` packages, and have now spent many hours trying to get them to work for me.

It seems to me that the packages are configured to work on the documentation *templates* that Workbench produces, but I want to adapt the `Transmogrify` process to work on a proper documentation notebook, meaning a documentation notebook as one would see them in the documentation center. E.g. [`Print`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/90f8d695-9a2d-41718bcb-105c03b41525) ([deep-linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147377/38205) to open in Mathematica)

I know this is not oft-used and wholly undocumented functionality, but is there any way I can do this?

(It seems like I may have to write a whole new set of XMLTransforms, but looking through them I don't quite know why they don't work and any guidance would be appreciated).

Comment: Function that takes "built" documentation notebook and creates a web page is ``DocumentationBuild`Export`ExportWebPage`` had any luck with it? Related: [How can I build documentation using docbuild.xml outside of the Workbench?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131104/14303).

Comment: @jkuczm I found that but when it kept spitting out errors I figured it was intended to be applied to a template (that kinda worked), so I looked at how it was defined and tried to adapt that for my built pages.

Comment: Could you add, to your question, a minimal example of "proper documentation notebook"?

Comment: @jkuczm does that suffice? I'm building the docs myself not using the Workbench templates, but I can put up an example of one of those doc pages. (But it doesn't work for the system docs, either)

Comment: Which version of Workbench are you using precisely? `ExportWebPage[FileNameJoin@{NotebookDirectory[], "Print.html"}, "Print.nb", {"Title" -> "Print", "TitleModifier" -> "", "HistoryData" -> {}, "EntityType" -> "Symbol", "Keywords" -> {}, "TutorialCollectionLinks" -> {}}]` works for me without problems in version 10.1.811, in 10.1.822 I get some messages, but they seem unimportant, and web page is created together with appropriate assets.

Comment: @jkuczm I'll need to check. I downloaded it via Eclipse only like two days ago, but don't know what version it is exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60700/discussion-between-b3m2a1-and-jkuczm).

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

The Workbench packages are out-of-date for 11.1 and the whole system is not configured to easily work from Mathematica using a structure differing from the standard `/language/ref` URL structure or things like that.

It's a massive pain to make it all work, but in the end we can get half-way decent, largely-functional documentation pages like [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/reference/BTools/ref/GenerateHTMLDocumentation.html)

---

#### Shameless Self-Promotion:

I added this system + auto-generation into my [DocGen package](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/DocGen.m) letting me build out docs like [this PacletManager documentation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/reference/PacletManager/guide/PacletManager.html) using just the following:

```
(* Build out the docs from the contexts*)
GenerateDocumentation[
 {
  "PacletTools`",
  "PacletManager`",
  "DataPaclets`"
  },
 "Install" -> True
 ]

(* Generate HTML and web deploy from paclets *)
GenerateHTMLDocumentation[
 PacletFind[{"*Paclet*", "0"}],
 CloudDeploy -> True
 ]
```

---

## Full Answer

To automate the entire process takes many tedious steps, but if you don't mind doing things by hand and  follow Frank Martin's guide [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/workbench-2-and-3-documentation-html-build-fails-output-file-test-failed) and don't mind doing things by hand you only really need the first two steps.

#### *Copy the packages from Eclipse*

Install Workbench on Eclipse, as described [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221).

Then find the directory where the documentation packages are stored:

```
$eclipsePath = "path/to/Eclipse";
FileNames["DocumentationBuild", $eclipsePath, \[Infinity]]
```

Copy `"DocumentationTools"`, `"DocumentationBuild"` and `"Transmogrify"` to `FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}`, then delete the `MenuSetup` that's in `"DocumentationTools"` (just for safety)

#### *11.1 to 11.0 Down Conversion*

The heart of my initial problem was that the build tools I copied over from Workbench were out of date, so I got around that by down-converting my notebooks to 11.0 style before passing them through `ExportWebPage`.

Here's the code I used for that:

```
webExportNotebookPrep[nb_] :=
 DeleteCases[
   Visible -> False
   ]@
  ReplaceRepeated[
   nb, {
    Cell[TextData[{c_, ___}], "ObjectNameGrid", ___] :>
     c,
    Cell[_, "NotesThumbnails" | "ObjectNameTranslation", ___] :>
     Sequence @@ {},
    Cell[TextData[{Cell[BoxData[_DynamicBox], ___], e__}],
      t : "NotesSection" | "PrimaryExamplesSection" |
        "ExampleSection" | "ExampleSubsection", r___] :>
     Cell[TextData[e], t, r],
    DynamicBox[e : If[$VersionNumber < _, __], ___] :>
     e,
    Cell[TextData[s_String], r___] :> Cell[s, r],
    t : TemplateBox[{_, _String}, ___] :>
     refLinkRewind[t],
    TagBox[a : ActionMenuBox[_FrameBox, ___], 
      MouseAppearanceTag["LinkHand"]] :>
     a,
    Cell[
      TextData[{t_, " ",
        Cell[
         BoxData[
          GraphicsBox[{{
             {
              _GrayLevel, _Thickness,
              LineBox[{{-1.8, 0.5}, {0, 0}, {1.8, 0.5}}]
              }
             }},
           ___
           ]
          ],
         ___
         ]
        }],
      ___
      ] :>
     InterpretationBox[
      Cell[
       TextData[{
         t,
         StyleBox[" \[FilledDownTriangle]", "AnchorBarArrow",
          StripOnInput -> False]
         }]],
      TextCell[
       Row[{"See Also", 
         Style[" \[FilledDownTriangle]", "AnchorBarArrow"]}]
       ]
      ]
    }
   ]
```

With those corrections we can get out raw HTML, but there are still many issue to correct, which are largely documented by Frank Martin, which I dealt with programmatically.

---

#### *File Post-Processing*

Some resources we want to link do built for a specific directory layout, corrupted or inadequate.

We'll write a general purpose function for handling this post-processing.

```
webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements // Clear;
webExportPostProcessMultiReplacements // Clear;

(* MultiReplacements *)

webExportPostProcessMultiReplacements[strip_, res_, url_] :=
  With[{
    trimmedRes =
     StringTrim[res, "/" ~~ EndOfString],
    paddedRes =
     StringTrim[res, "/" ~~ EndOfString] <> "/"
    },
   Flatten@{(*
     (* Insert prototype into loaded JS characters *)

     "<script src='javascript/common.js' type='text/javascript'></script>\n"<>

          "<script src='javascript/jquery.js' \
type='text/javascript'></script>\n"->

     "<script src='javascript/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>\n"<>

          "<script src='javascript/common.js' \
type='text/javascript'></script>\n",*)
     (* Relink loaded JS and CSS *)

       h : ("src" | "href") ~~ "=" ~~ (q : "'" | "\"") ~~ 
       t : "javascript" | "css" ~~ "/" :>

      h <> "=" <> q <> URLBuild@{res, t} <> "/",
     h : ("src" | "href") ~~ "=" ~~ (q : "'" | "\"") ~~ "/" ~~ 
       t : "javascript" | "css" ~~ "/" :>

      h <> "=" <> q <> URLBuild@{res, t} <> "/",
     "/webMathematica/Resources/Documentation/English/" ->
      paddedRes,
     (* Relink loaded JS and CSS *)

     l : ("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" ~~
         (paddedRes | "") ~~ 
         "css/reference.css\" />") :>

      l <> "\n<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" <>

       URLBuild@{trimmedRes, "css", "clipboard.css"} <> "\" />",
     l : ("<script src=\"" ~~ (paddedRes | "") ~~ 
         "javascript/reference.js\"></script>") :>

      "<script src=\"" <>
       URLBuild@{trimmedRes, "javascript",
         "jquery", "core", "1.7.2", "jquery.min.js"} <> "\" /></script>\n" <> l
     }
   ];

(* SingleReplacements *)

webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements[strip_, res_, url_] :=
  With[{
    trimmedRes =
     StringTrim[res, "/" ~~ EndOfString],
    paddedRes =
     StringTrim[res, "/" ~~ EndOfString] <> "/"
    },
   Flatten@{
     Replace[strip, Except[_List | _Rule] -> {}],
     (* Protect true links *)

     "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/" ~~

       t : "ref" | "guide" | "tutorial" :>

      "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/" <> t,
     paddedRes ~~
       t : "ref" | "guide" | "tutorial" :>
      "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/" <> t,
     "/language/" ~~
       t : "ref" | "guide" | "tutorial" :>

      URLBuild@{
        "http://reference.wolfram.com/language",
        t
        },
     (* Patch intra site links *)

     "/language/" ~~ param : Except[WhitespaceCharacter] ... ~~

       t : "ref" | "guide" | "tutorial" ~~

       doc : Except[WhitespaceCharacter | "\""] ... :>
      URLBuild@
       DeleteCases[{url, StringTrim[param, "/"], t, StringTrim[doc, "/"]}, ""],
     "http://reference.wolfram.com/language" ->
      url,
     (* Patch resource directory *)
     "/common/" ->
      paddedRes,
     (* Patch jquery version *)

     "jquery/core/1.6.1" ->
      "jquery/core/1.7.2",
     (* Patch mathematicaImages to work a resource base *)

     "\"../" ~~ i : "images/mathematicaImages" :>

      "\"" <> URLBuild@{trimmedRes, i},
     "\"" ~~ i : "images/mathematicaImages" :>

      "\"" <> URLBuild@{trimmedRes, i},
     "\"/mathematicaImages" ->

      "\"" <> URLBuild@{trimmedRes, "images", "mathematicaImages"},
     (* Patch includes to work a resource base *)

     "\"/includes" ->
      "\"" <> URLBuild@{trimmedRes, "includes"},
     (* Downconvert 2013 resources to the standard resoruce base *)

     "/2013/" ->
      paddedRes,
     (* Delete duplicates *)
     (l : 
         "<script src=\"" <>

          URLBuild@{trimmedRes, "javascript", "jquery.min.js"} <> 
          "\" /></script>\n") .. :>
      l,
     (l : "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" <>

          URLBuild@{trimmedRes, "css", "clipboard.css"} <> "\" />\n") .. :>

          l
     }
   ];

(* Extension specific replacements *)

webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements["css", strip_, res_, url_] :=
  {
   (* Add clipboard styles into reference.css *)

   t : "/*##############################\n\tCOLORS" :>
    "/* clipboard styles */\n@import url('clipboard.css');\n" <> t
   };

webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements["js", strip_, res_, url_] :=
  {
   (* Clean up dangerous characters while protecting whitespace *)

   w : WhitespaceCharacter :> w,
   _?(Not@*PrintableASCIIQ) -> ""   
   };

webExportPostProcessMultiReplacements[_, _, _, _] :=
  {
   };
webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements[_, _, _, _] :=
  {
   };

(* Main *)

webExportPostProcess // Clear

Options[webExportPostProcess] = {
   "ResourceBase" -> Automatic,
   "URLBase" -> Automatic,
   "StripExtensions" -> Automatic
   };
webExportPostProcess[file_String?FileExistsQ, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

  With[{
    s = ReadString[file],
    ext = Replace[OptionValue["StripExtensions"], 
      Automatic -> {".en." -> "."}],
    res =
     Replace[OptionValue["ResourceBase"],
      Automatic :>
       URLBuild@
        ConstantArray["..",
         With[{split = FileNameSplit@DirectoryName@file},
          SelectFirst[Range[Length@split],
           DirectoryQ@FileNameJoin@
              Append[
               Drop[split, -#],
               "javascript"
               ] &,
           1
           ]
          ]
         ]
      ],
    url =
     Replace[OptionValue["URLBase"],
      Automatic :>
       URLBuild@
        ConstantArray["..",
         With[{split = FileNameSplit@DirectoryName@file},
          SelectFirst[Range[Length@split],
           DirectoryQ@FileNameJoin@
              Append[
               Drop[split, -#],
               "javascript"
               ] &,
           1
           ]
          ]
         ]
      ]
    },
   If[StringQ[s],
    DeleteFile[file];
    Export[
     StringReplace[file,
      Replace[OptionValue["StripExtensions"], Except[_List | _Rule] -> {}]
      ],
     FixedPoint[#, s, 6] &@
       StringReplace@Join[
         webExportPostProcessMultiReplacements[
          ext,
          res,
          url
          ],
         webExportPostProcessMultiReplacements[
          FileExtension[file],
          ext,
          res,
          url
          ]
         ] //
      StringReplace@Join[
        webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements[
         ext,
         res,
         url
         ],
        webExportPostProcessSingleReplacements[
         FileExtension[file],
         ext,
         res,
         url
         ]
        ]
     ,
     "Text"
     ],
    file
    ]
   ];
webExportPostProcess[___] := $Failed
```

---

#### *Resource copying*

Then we'll take jkuczm's resource list to copy from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131104/how-can-i-build-documentation-using-docbuild-xml-outside-of-the-workbench/131569#131569) and copy each file to the documentation directory with requisite post-processing:

```
$webExportAssets :=
  Map[
   <|
     "Drop" -> FileNameDepth[#[[1]]] - FileNameDepth@#[[2]],
     "Files" -> FileNames[#[[3]], #[[1]], \[Infinity]],
     "Insert" -> If[Length@# > 3, #[[4]], Nothing]
     |> &,
   {
    {
     FileNameJoin@{
       DocumentationBuild`Common`$DocumentationBuildDirectory,
       "Internal", "web", "html", "javascript"
       },
     "javascript",
     {
      "*.js"
      }
     },
    {
     FileNameJoin@{
       DocumentationBuild`Common`$DocumentationBuildDirectory,
       "Internal", "web", "html", "css"
       },
     "css",
     {
      "*.css"
      }
     },
    {
     FileNameJoin@{
       DocumentationBuild`Common`$DocumentationBuildDirectory,
       "Internal", "web", "html", "2014", "standard"
       },
     "",
     {
      "*.js", "*.json", "*.css", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.jpg",
      "*.svg", "*.eot", "*.otf", "*.ttf", "*.woff", "*.html"
      }
     },
    {
     FileNameJoin@{
       DocumentationBuild`Common`$DocumentationBuildDirectory,
       "Internal", "web", "html", "2014", "standard"
       },
     "",
     {
      "*.ttf", "*.woff"
      },
     "fonts"
     },
    {
     FileNameJoin@{
       DocumentationBuild`Common`$DocumentationBuildDirectory,
       "Internal", "web", "html", "2014",
       "minimal",
       "javascript"
       },
     "javascript",
     "faster-page-load.js"
     },
    {
     FileNameJoin@{
       DocumentationBuild`Common`$DocumentationBuildDirectory,
       "Internal", "web", "html", "images",
       "mathematicaImages"
       },
     FileNameJoin@{"images", "mathematicaImages"},
     "bullet.gif"
     }
    }
   ];

webExportAssetsCopy[dir : (_String | _File)?DirectoryQ] :=

  Block[{d, f},
   Monitor[
    Table[
     With[{depth = a["Drop"], insert = a["Insert"]},
      Table[
       d =
        FileNameJoin@
         Flatten@{dir,
           DirectoryName@FileNameDrop[f, depth],
           insert
           };
       If[! DirectoryQ@d,
        CreateDirectory[d,
         CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True
         ]
        ];
       If[StringMatchQ[FileExtension[#], "css" | "js" | "html"],
          webExportPostProcess[#],
          #
          ] &@
        CopyFile[f,
         FileNameJoin@
          Flatten@{
            d,
            FileNameTake@f
            },
         OverwriteTarget -> True
         ],
       {f, a["Files"]}
       ]
      ],
     {a, $webExportAssets}
     ],
    Internal`LoadingPanel[
     "Copying `` to ``"~TemplateApply~
      {
       f,
       FileNameJoin@
        Flatten@{
          d,
          FileNameTake@f
          }
       }
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

---

#### *HTML Generation*

With all of that in place we can now generate pages that will look right:

```
webExportNotebook[file_, nb_, ops___?OptionQ] :=

 With[{params = Flatten@{ops}},
  Needs["DocumentationBuild`"];
  Block[{
    DocumentationBuild`Common`PubsEvaluateWithFE =
     Identity,
    DocumentationBuild`Common`Private`PubsStartFrontEnd =
     Identity,
    Print =
     Identity,
    NotebookOpen,
    NotebookPut,
    expFile =
     If[DirectoryQ@file,
      FileNameJoin@Flatten@{
          file,
          URLParse[
           Lookup[params, "URI",
            URLBuild@{
              "",
              "DocPage-" <> ToString[RandomInteger[10000]]
              }
            ],
           "Path"]
          } <> ".html",
      file
      ]
    },
   NotebookOpen[e___] :=
    MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
     FrontEnd`NotebookOpenReturnObject[e, Visible -> False]
     ];
   NotebookPut[e_] :=
    MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
     FrontEnd`NotebookPutReturnObject[Append[e, Visible -> False]]
     ];
   Quiet[
    DocumentationBuild`Export`ExportWebPage[
     ExpandFileName[expFile],
     webExportNotebookPrep@nb,
     Normal@params,
     Sequence @@
      FilterRules[
       Flatten@{
         ops,
         "CompleteHTMLQ" -> True
         },
       FilterRules[
        Options[DocumentationBuild`Export`ExportWebPage],
        Except["HistoryData" | "Language"]
        ]
       ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Where we'll feed the result of gathering the notebook metadata parameters in as `ops`:

```
$webExportParameters =
  {
   "title" -> "Title",
   "titlemodifier" -> "TitleModifier",
   "history" -> "HistoryData",
   "type" -> "EntityType",
   "paclet" -> "PacletName",
   "context" -> "Context",
   "uri" -> "URI",
   "keywords" -> "Keywords",
   "tutorialcollectionlinks" -> "TutorialCollectionLinks",
   "summary" -> "Summary",
   "index" -> "IndexQ"
   };

webExportGatherParameters[nb_, ops___?OptionQ] :=
  Normal@
   KeyMap[
    Capitalize@*
     Replace[$webExportParameters],
    Association@
     FilterRules[
      Flatten@{
        ops,
        Fold[Lookup, 
         Options[nb, TaggingRules], {TaggingRules, "Metadata"}]
        },
      Alternatives @@ 
       Flatten[Through@{Keys, Values}[$webExportParameters]]
      ]
    ];
```

Note that the export process also blocks / changes a lot of things that Workbench uses that we don't need, e.g opens the notebook in hidden form, prevents a new front-end from being configured, and has the `Transmogrify` process work in quieted mode.

---

#### *Composite function*

We can then build all this into a single function:

```
Options[GenerateHTMLDocumentation] =
  Join[
   Options[GenerateSymbolPages],
   Options[webExportPostProcess],
   Options[DocumentationBuild`Export`ExportWebPage],
   Options[webExportAssetsDeploy], {
    CloudConnect -> Automatic,
    CloudDeploy -> False,
    "DeployAssets" -> False,
    "CopyAssets" -> Automatic
    }];
GenerateHTMLDocumentation[dir_String?DirectoryQ,
   nb : {__Notebook} | None,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  With[{
    deploy = OptionValue[CloudDeploy],
    highlight =
     CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,
      {AutoStyleOptions, "HighlightUndefinedSymbols"}
      ]
    },
   If[
    TrueQ@OptionValue["CopyAssets"] ||
     And[
      OptionValue["CopyAssets"] === Automatic || 
       TrueQ@OptionValue["DeployAssets"],
      AnyTrue[{"css", "fonts", "images", "includes", "javascript"},
       Not@DirectoryQ[FileNameJoin@{dir, #}] &
       ]
      ],
    webExportAssetsCopy[dir]
    ];
   CheckAbort[
    Function[
      CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,
        {AutoStyleOptions, "HighlightUndefinedSymbols"}
        ] =
       highlight;
      If[deploy,
       Replace[
        Replace[OptionValue[CloudConnect],
         Automatic -> Key["PacletsAccount"]
         ], {
         s_String :>
          If[$WolframID =!= s,
           CloudConnect[s]
           ],
         {s__String} :>
          CloudConnect[s],
         k_Key :>
          KeyChainConnect[k]
         }]
       ];
      If[deploy && OptionValue["DeployAssets"],
       Replace[
        Replace[OptionValue["ResourceBase"], {
          Automatic -> "reference",
          CloudObject[c_, ___] :> c
          }],
        s_String :>
         webExportAssetsDeploy[dir, s,
          FilterRules[
           {
            ops
            },
           Options@webExportAssetsDeploy
           ]
          ]
        ]
       ];
      If[deploy,
       Replace[
        Replace[OptionValue["URLBase"], {
          Automatic -> "reference",
          CloudObject[c_, ___] :> c
          }],
        s_String :>
         If[# =!= None,
          webExportCloudDeploy[dir, #, s,
           FilterRules[
            {
             ops
             },
            Options@webExportCloudDeploy
            ]
           ]
          ]
        ],
       #
       ]
      ]@
     If[nb === None,
      None,
      If[Length@nb > 1,
         Monitor[ReleaseHold[#],
          Internal`LoadingPanel[
           "Generating HTML page `` of ``"
            ~TemplateApply~
            {i, Length@nb}
           ]
          ],
         ReleaseHold@#
         ] &@
       Hold@
        Table[
         With[{
           params = webExportGatherParameters[nb[[i]], ops]
           },
          webExportPostProcess[
           webExportNotebook[dir, nb[[i]], params],
           FilterRules[
            Flatten@{
              If[deploy,

               "URLBase" ->

                Replace[OptionValue["URLBase"], {

                  Automatic :>

                   First@CloudObject["reference"],
                  CloudObject[u_, ___] :>
                   u,
                  s_String :>
                   First@CloudObject[s]
                  }],
               Nothing
               ],
              If[deploy,

               "ResourceBase" ->

                Replace[OptionValue["ResourceBase"], {

                  Automatic :>

                   First@CloudObject["reference"],
                  CloudObject[u_, ___] :>
                   u,
                  s_String :>
                   First@CloudObject[s]
                  }],
               Nothing
               ],
              params
              },
            Options[webExportPostProcess]
            ]
           ]
          ],
         {i, Length@nb}
         ]

      ],
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,
      {AutoStyleOptions, "HighlightUndefinedSymbols"}
      ] =
     highlight;
    $Aborted
    ]
   ];
```

Then we merge it with the automatic documentation generation process I wrote up [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146670/automating-documentation-generation/146671#146671):

```
GenerateHTMLDocumentation[
   dir : (_String | _File)?
      DirectoryQ | _FileName?(DirectoryQ@*ToFileName),
   pattern : _String?(Not@*FileExistsQ) | _Symbol,
   ops___?OptionQ
   ] :=
  With[{n = Names[pattern]},
   If[Length@n > 1,
    $Failed,
    With[{
      nb =
       First[{NotebookGet[#], NotebookClose[#]}] &@
        First@Flatten@List@
           GenerateSymbolPages[
            Evaluate@First@n,
            Evaluate@FilterRules[{ops}, Options@GenerateSymbolPages],
            Visible -> False
            ]
      },
     GenerateHTMLDocumentation[
      Replace[dir, f_FileName :> ToFileName[f]],
      nb,
      ops
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

And then let it generate the docs without specifying a directory:

```
$webDocsHTMLBuildDirectory =
  FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory, "web_docs"};
GenerateHTMLDocumentation[
  Optional[Automatic, Automatic],
  s___
  ] :=
 With[{dir =
    Quiet[
     DeleteDirectory[$webDocsHTMLBuildDirectory, 
      DeleteContents -> True];
     CreateDirectory[$webDocsHTMLBuildDirectory]
     ]},
  GenerateHTMLDocumentation[
   dir,
   s
   ]
  ]
```

---

#### *Viewing / Deploy the Docs*

Some things in the docs require HTTP, so to view the docs we make we'll want a function to start a server in a directory. It doesn't look like `` HTTPHandling`StartWebServer `` does that so we'll need something else. I chose to use python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

I put some sugar on it in my [PyTools package](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/PyTools.m). Look for `PySimpleServerStart` and `PySimpleServerOpen`.

But long-term having local docs is rather useless so I chose to put mine in the cloud, using these two functions to copy the resources and files up:

```
Options[webExportAssetsDeploy] =
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@
   Join[
    {
     Permissions -> "Public"
     },
    Options[CloudObject]
    ];
webExportAssetsDeploy[
  dir_String?DirectoryQ,
  uri_String,
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 With[{
   files =
    Select[
     FileNames[
      "css" | "fonts" | "images" | "includes" | 
        "javascript" ~~
       $PathnameSeparator <> "*",
      dir,
      \[Infinity]],
     Not@*DirectoryQ
     ]
   },
  Block[{f},
   Monitor[
    Table[
     CopyFile[
      f,
      CloudObject[
       URLBuild@
        Flatten@{uri, 
          FileNameSplit@FileNameDrop[f, FileNameDepth@dir]},
       Sequence @@ FilterRules[Flatten@{
           ops,
           Options[webExportAssetsDeploy]
           },
         Options[CloudObject]
         ]
       ]
      ],
     {f, files}
     ],
    Internal`LoadingPanel[
     "Copying `` to ``"~TemplateApply~
      {
       f,
       URLBuild@Flatten@{uri,
          FileNameSplit@FileNameDrop[f, FileNameDepth@dir]}
       }
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]

Options[webExportCloudDeploy] =
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@
   Join[
    {
     Permissions -> "Public"
     },
    Options[CloudObject]
    ];
webExportCloudDeploy[
  dir_String?DirectoryQ,
  pages : {__String?FileExistsQ},
  uri_String,
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 With[{
   files =
    Join[
     pages,
     Select[
      FileNames[
       "Files" <> $PathnameSeparator ~~

        Alternatives @@ 
         Map[FileBaseName, pages] ~~
        $PathnameSeparator <> "*",
       DirectoryName@First@pages,
       \[Infinity]],
      Not@*DirectoryQ
      ]
     ]
   },
  Block[{f},
   Monitor[
    Table[
     Take[#, 1] &@
      CopyFile[
       f,
       CloudObject[
        URLBuild@
         Flatten@{uri,
           FileNameSplit@FileNameDrop[f, FileNameDepth@dir]},
        Sequence @@ FilterRules[
          Flatten@{
            ops,
            Options[webExportCloudDeploy]
            },
          Options[CloudObject]
          ]
        ]
       ],
     {f, files}
     ],
    Internal`LoadingPanel[
     "Copying `` to ``"~TemplateApply~
      {
       f,
       URLBuild@Flatten@{uri,
          FileNameSplit@FileNameDrop[f, FileNameDepth@dir]}
       }
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

(Note that they're already included in `GenerateHTMLDocumentation`)

---

#### *End Product*

After all of that we have docs that are (mostly) functional and in the cloud. Here's an example of what this is good for:

```
In[60]:= GenerateHTMLDocumentation[ 
 GenerateHTMLDocumentation,
 CloudDeploy -> True, 
 "CopyAssets" -> False
 ]

Out[60]= CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.docs/reference/BTools/ref/GenerateHTMLDocumentation.html"]
```

If we then go to https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/docs/BTools/ref/GenerateHTMLDocumentation.html we get a mostly functional 11.0 style documentation page:

[image: docs]

Comment: Crazy,man... :)

Comment: Great work! I wanted to do this for a while now! :)

Comment: This is very cool!  I tried downloading your BTools package to use `GenerateHTMLDocumentation[]` on my documentation pages.  Unfortunately, it keeps asking me "Download the DocumentationBuild and Transmogrify packages?", even after pressing OK all the time.  Is there a place from where I can download these modified packages?  Or do I need to do this manually?

Comment: @QuantumDot ah I must have screwed that checking function up. I'll patch it. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151764/38205) in the meantime. If you want a smaller package to work with, look at the [`DocGen` package](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-DocGen) I forked [for someone else](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146670/automating-documentation-generation/146671#comment410194_146671).

Comment: @QuantumDot that's patched. I didn't fully qualify the `PacletInstall`. One thing to beware of is it uses my resources by default when you deploy it. You'll want to set `$DocDefaultURLBase` to your own site. I'll migrate the change to the smaller `DocGen` paclet too.

Comment: Oh! I see!  I'm supposed to use Mathematica 11!  It doesn't work with Mathematica 10 or lower.

Comment: @QuantumDot unfortunately I haven't gotten around to making it 10 compatible. It takes a fair bit of work to figure out how to convert a built doc page into something workable and I don't have 10 docs anymore. If you don't mind sharing a doc page, a guide page, with me I can try to make it work with 10.

Comment: @QuantumDot although, if you build the docs with `"BTools`"` or `"DocGen`"` they're 11 ready. By the way, if you use Workbench to make your docs `"Transmogrify`"` and `"DocumentationBuild`"` come with it.

Comment: No problem at all-- I have Mathematica 11; and I successfully got it to work on my documentation pages, and it's so juicy sweet!  Thank you for this package!  I prefer to use *Workbench* to create my documentation since then I can use jkuczm's [WWBCommon](https://github.com/jkuczm/WWBCommon) to create cross-version compatible documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64088/discussion-between-quantumdot-and-b3m2a1).

Answer (score 5):

Starting in Wolfram v13.0, there is initial official in-language support for HTML documentation builds, via the new [`PacletDocumentationBuild`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PacletTools/ref/PacletDocumentationBuild.html) function. Also new in v13.0 is the `Palettes > Documentation Tools` palette, which is used to author new documentation pages.

Using Documentation Tools and `PacletDocumentationBuild`, it is now possible to author and build documentation entirely from within Mathematica / Wolfram Desktop.

However, there are some caveats. While these tools are available and useable right now, we're still working on fully documenting how to best use them. And the HTML building functionality is still new, and the rendered HTML may have visual glitches.

Some notes:

- The layout and styling of the web content produced by `PacletDocumentationBuild` is up-to-date — these are the latest styles used by the official Wolfram Language documentation at reference.wolfram.com.

  - `PacletDocumentationBuild` uses the same code as we do internally to build the Wolfram Language documentation notebooks and web docs. It will stay up to date as time goes on.
- `PacletDocumentationBuild` is specifically intended for building documentation that is part of a paclet. If you have documentation that is not part of a paclet, you will need to create a paclet for it in order to use this function.
- You can build and publish HTML directly to the cloud:

  ```
  PacletDocumentationBuild["/path/to/YourPaclet", CloudObject["MyPacletDocs"], "HTML"]
  ```

See [my answer to *"What are the best resources for paclet development?"*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262964/82154) to learn more about creating paclets and authoring documentation using these tools.