# Download DocumentationBuild and Transmogrify without Eclipse

Tags: documentation, workbench

I've been playing with the [HTML docs system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148596/using-documentationbuild-and-transmogrify-to-generate-web-docs) recently, but want to download the core packages from the source (for downstream users / fun).

My digging has gotten me this far:

the DocumentationBuild (etc.) packages are downloaded to a folder called MathematicaSource *only when the runtime is started from Eclipse*. What I mean is given an application layout in the Eclipse plugin:

[image: layout]

the download doesn't occur until the notebook is opened (from the kernel that Eclipse starts).

And every time that runtime is started it will redownload if the packages don't exist.

Try opening the testing notebook (to start the runtime), then opening the DocumentationTools palette then running this:

```
Notebooks["DocumentationTools.nb"][[1]] // NotebookDirectory // 
  Nest[ParentDirectory, #, 3] & // 
 DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True] &
```

This will clear the MathematicaSource directory.

Then quit, re-open the testing notebook, and voilà, the packages are back (after a long loading period that must be the download of the packages).

This is stretching the *Mathematica* part of the Mathematica StackExchange, but can I figure out what that download path is? Using [`$CommandLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$CommandLine.html.en) unfortunately doesn't solve the problem as the configuration is just the standard one. And there's nothing in the Autoload directories.

I tried going from the plugin-download site, but these packages are, obviously, not downloaded then and so looking at http://workbench.wolfram.com/update/artifacts.xml is really rather useless.

Anyone know how to get this? I'd really prefer the option for a simple download over having to download via workbench, open a testing notebook, then copy the packages out.

Answer (score 5):

Until I find where this lives I just put the paclets in my paclets cloud account.
 Here's [DocumentationBuild](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/paclets/DocumentationBuild/Paclets/DocumentationBuild-1.0.0.paclet) and here's [Transmogrify](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/paclets/Transmogrify/Paclets/Transmogrify-1.0.0.paclet).

So you can download them via [`PacletInstall`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/reference/PacletManager/ref/PacletInstall.html):

```
PacletInstall[
 "DocumentationBuild",
 "Site"-> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/DocumentationBuild"
 ]
PacletInstall[
 "Transmogrify",
 "Site"-> "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/Transmogrify"
 ]
```

Comment: I think your links are broken.  Would you kindly look into it?

Comment: @QuantumDot ah yes they probably are. I've been reorilganizing how I store my paclets. I'll patch it.

Comment: Ok, cool; let me know when you do so I can re-download them.

Comment: @QuantumDot done

Comment: Hmm.. they are returning `$Failed`, and when I point my browser to https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/DocumentationBuild, I get "access denied" (403).  The other links in your post remain broken (404).  Perhaps also, could you update the `GenerateHTMLDocumentation` function so that the auto-downloader also points to the correct spot?

Comment: @QuantumDot updated it. The actual file is here: http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/Transmogrify/Paclets/Transmogrify-1.0.0.paclet and here: http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/DocumentationBuild/Paclets/DocumentationBuild-1.0.0.paclet The syntax in the answer finds that automatically. It's just a little bit cleaner.